# Combining 2 different cut outputs in a single command?

Tags: text-processing, cut

I have a file such as the following:

```
1234
ABCD
EFGH
```

I'd like to convert it to the following:

```
2341
BCDA
FGHE
```

The actual file has 4,000 words, so I would like to do this in an efficient manner. I tried using the command `cut -c 2-4,1 file.txt`, but it produces the same exact output as the input. I was thinking I could use 3 different commands:

```
cut -c 1 file.txt > temp1.txt
cut -c 2-4 file.txt > temp2.txt
// combine the two with paste or pr
```

... but I would prefer a single command because I need to run it several times with slight modifications so running one command is less error prone than running 3 commands each time.

Is there any way to combine the 2 cut statements into one? Something like:

```
cut -c 1 file.txt | pr (cut -c 2-4 file.txt)
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's:^\(.\)\(.*\):\2\1:' file.txt

2341
BCDA
FGHE
```

Answer (score 13):

With `cut` and `paste` you can also do an one-liner:

```
$ cat file
1234
ABCD
EFGH
$ paste --delimiter=''  <(cut file -c2-4) <(cut file -c1)
2341
BCDA
FGHE
```

Comment: +1, for the paste shortcut. It is easily understandable. :)

Comment: You can also just use `-d ''` instead of `--delimiters=''` to
              reuse characters from LIST instead of TABs

Answer (score 4):

If you use bash, use the string indexing of [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
while IFS= read -r word; do
  echo "${word:1:3}${word:0:1}"
done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat test
1234
ABCD
EFGH
$ awk -F "" '{print $2$3$4$1}' test
2341
BCDA
FGHE
```

You can change the separator via "-F" according to your data, and arrange the order of fields arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way with `perl`:

```
perl -F'' -lane 'print @F[1..@F], $F[0]'
```

Auto-split at letter boundaries, rotate one to the left and print.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative in a script way:

```
~$ cut -c2- file.txt>file2.txt
~$ cut -c1 file.txt>file3.txt
~$ paste -d "" file2.txt file3.txt>file4.txt
~$ rm file2.txt file3.txt
```

The script cuts the chains in a separate files.
Then join into a new file (file4.txt)
And finally removes the spare files.

the llua solution is more clean for my taste.

Answer (score -1):

Have you  tried rev ?

`~$ cat filename | rev`

Comment: Take a look at the sample output. It's not a pure reverse, but good thinking. If you can't come up with a way to re-work this you should probably delete it, just so that it doesn't get downvoted and confuse the thread.