# Reorder fields/characters with cut command

Tags: text-processing, cut

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combining 2 different cut outputs in a single command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47048/combining-2-different-cut-outputs-in-a-single-command)

I have One file - temp.txt - which contains

```
ABCDF

PQRST

LMNOP
```

I tried this `cut` command

```
$ cut -c 2-5 temp.txt
BCDF

QRST

MNOP
```

output is right.

```
$ cut -c 1,2,3,4 temp.txt
ABCD

PQRS

LMNO
```

output is right.

But when I change sequence, meaning

```
$ cut -c 2-4,1 temp.txt
ABCD

PQRS

LMNO
```

above output displayed.

but logically output is

```
BCDA

QRSP

MNOL
```

so my question is how this happen ,any reason behind that.

Comment: I think that cut CANNOT mix chars! You have to do a simple "hack" like this: `echo -n ${string:1:3}; echo ${string:0:1}` but you have to first grep you string :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The explanation is in `man cut`, though it is easy to read it as your preferred expectation. However it does say:

```
Selected input is written in the same order that it is read
```

It is perhaps ambiguous as to what is meant by input, but typically Options are just that, options, whereas the file being processes is definitely *input*.

The `list`, eg.`-c 2,3,4,1` is very much like the regex list: `[2341]`; It means any of the numbers in the list, even if they are doubled up.. eg. `-c 2,2,2,2,2,2` is the same as `-c 2` .. and for the regex, `[2222222]` is the same as `[2]`... So the order of your options is not relevant.

Comment: there's nothing that prevents an option from being read as an ordered list instead of as a set

Answer (score 5):

The solution is:

```
sed 's:^\(.\)\(.*\):\2\1:' file.txt
```

(someone published this answer to a similar question yesterday)

Cut seems not to order the output, only select ranges of columns/fields and output in the same order as they were.

Comment: If you came to this question for reordering other fields (not single characters), the awk is much more readable: `awk -F, '{print $2","$1}'`